# Keyword Search in microservices based architecture

Tags: search, solr, microservices

I need some advice as to how a search needs to be implemented to search keywords within relational databases owned by microservices.
I have some microservices with their own relational DB. These microservices are likely to be deployed in a docker container.
What would be the best way to use a search engine like Apache SOLR so that each of the microservices' database can be indexed and we can achieve keyword search

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an architectural question and while it makes sense, the question is also a little open ended depending on what your system requires. A couple of things that come off the top of my head is:

1. Use the [DataImportHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) from Apache SOLR.
2. Use a message queue like Kafka or Kinesis and have the independent services consume from it to propagate to their data stores in this case, a search service backed by Apache SOLR and another service backed by MySQL.

Personally, I've never used the DataImportHandler myself but my initial thoughts are that it couples Apache SOLR to MySQL. Setting up the DataImportHandler requires Apache SOLR to know the MySQL schema, the access credentials, etc. Because of this, I would advise the second option which moves towards a **shared-nothing** architecture.

I'm going to call the service that is backed by MySQL the "entity" service as it sounds like its going to be the canonical service for saving some particular type of object. The entity service and the search service will have its own particular consumer that ingests events from Kinesis or Kafka into their data stores, the search service to Apache SOLR and the entity service to MySQL.

This helps decouple the services from knowing that each other exists and also allow each of them to scale independently from each other. It'll be a redundancy in data but it should be alright because the data access patterns are different.

The other caveat that I'd like to mention is that it assumes that the entity for which you're saving is allowed to be asynchronous. Notice that messages in this system doesn't require it to be persisted in MySQL at the moment which in this case is the entity service. However, you may change it to your liking such that a message persists in the entity service and then is propagated through a queue to a search service to index. After its been index, you can just add additional endpoints to search Apache SOLR. Hope this gives you some insight on how some other architectures may come into play. If you give a little more insight as to your system and the entities that involved, you might be able to get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Will
Mostly will be doing SOLR + DataImportHandler. Also since my database schema is highly relational, denormalizing the entire thing wouldnt make sense. I would rather have it still be relational in the DB layer and still decouple it in the application layer. I know this would cost me more remote calls, but I don't seem to find any other solution.
In which case, the database is going to be a single big database, and so DataImportHandler should do the indexing..

Comment: No problem! Glad I can help! That could definitely be a fine solution as long as it matches the business domain and the investment that is made up front. Though it sounds like you might be sharing a database where you might have different services read from. That in effect might cause tight coupling between your services via the schema. It might not be the best solution if you're looking to scale.